# Sound Control System

Tags: javascript, audio

This is my sound system that allows for the following functionality:

- One master volume that controls *every* sound.
- A function to stop/pause *every* playing sound
- A function to control every *instance* of a sounds volume(@creation)
- A function to stop/pause every *instance* of the same sound
- Sounds that are playing are kept in a list to keep track of.
- retrieve a list of specified sounds playing
- Retrieve a list of every sound playing

How could I possibly improve the code, or the system itself? I could possibly allow the user to define layers to encapsulate sectors of sound and not just the same instance. I could probably make a user.

```
  // exponentially decrease sounds
  this.Sound.masterVolume = function(v){ masterVolume = Math.pow(v,2);};
  this.Sound.instanceVolume = function(name, v){ instanceVolume[name] = Math.pow(v,2);};
  this.Sound.masterStop = function(){
    liveSounds.forEach(function(snd){
      snd.pause();
      snd.onended();
      snd.currentTime = 0;
    });
  }
  this.Sound.masterPause = function(){
    liveSounds.forEach(function(snd){
      snd.pause();
    });
  };
  this.Sound.instanceStop = function( name ){
    var match = sounds[name].src;
    liveSounds.forEach(function(snd){
      if( snd.src !== match ) return;
      snd.pause();
      snd.onended();
      snd.currentTime = 0;
    });
  };
  this.Sound.instancePause = function( name ){
    var match = sounds[name].src;
    liveSounds.forEach(function(snd){
      if( snd.src !==  match ) return;
      snd.pause();
    });
  }
  this.Sound.instanceGetLive = function( name ){
    return liveSounds.filter(function(snd){
      return( snd.src === match );
    });
  }
  this.Sound.masterGetLive = function(){
    return liveSounds.splice();//only a copy. 
  }

  this.sound = function(name){
    var snd = new Audio( sounds[name].src ),
        that = this;
    snd.volume = instanceVolume[name] || 1;
    snd.play = function(){
      this.volume *= masterVolume;
      Audio.prototype.play.apply(this);
      liveSounds.push(this);
      this.onended = function(){ liveSounds.splice( liveSounds.indexOf(snd), 1 );};
    };
    return snd;
  };
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you indicated what `this` was, as well as stuff like the context for `masterVolume` and `instanceVolume` -- are these globals? Having the enclosing closure would be super useful for reviewing.

Comment: @Schism It's apart of a larger system, and it's enclosed inside of a media object. I'll try uploading a better view of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get really far cleaning this up by just creating some private functions and bumping them to the bottom of the file so that they can be hoisted

```
  this.Sound.masterVolume = function(v){ masterVolume = Math.pow(v,2);};
  this.Sound.instanceVolume = function(name, v){ instanceVolume[name] = Math.pow(v,2);};
  this.Sound.masterStop = function(){ liveSounds.forEach(reset) }
  this.Sound.masterPause = function(){ liveSounds.forEach(pause) }
  this.Sound.instanceStop = function( name ){ liveSoundsExcept(name).forEach(reset) }
  this.Sound.instancePause = function( name ){ liveSoundsExcept(name).forEach(pause) }
  this.Sound.instanceGetLive = function( name ){
    //this seems to be an error - what is match?
    return liveSounds.filter(function(snd){
      return( snd.src === match );
    });
  }
  this.Sound.masterGetLive = function(){
    return liveSounds.slice(0);//slice generates a copy - I don't think splice does
  }

  this.sound = function(name){
    var snd = new Audio(getSound(name)); //reference to `this` removed because it wasn't being used
    snd.volume = instanceVolume[name] || 1;
    snd.play = function(){ 
      //why use the ambiguous `this` here? It can vary depending on how this is called - you already have an isntance of `snd`!
      snd.volume *= masterVolume;  
      //Audio.prototype.play.apply(snd); //Why? you can just use 
      snd.play();
      liveSounds.push(snd);
      // This can't be right - you don't need to do any cleanup?
      // this.onended = function(){ liveSounds.splice( liveSounds.indexOf(snd), 1 );};
    };
    return snd;
  };

  function getSound(name) { return sounds[name].src}
  function liveSoundsExcept(name) {
    var match = getSound(name);
    return liveSounds.filter(function(snd){ return snd.src !== match });
  }
  function pause(snd) { snd.pause(); }
  function reset(snd) {
    pause(snd);
    snd.onended();
    snd.currentTime = 0;
  }
```

I absolutely agree with @Schism that more context is needed for a really *good* review but I made a few other observations inline.

One that also jumps out at me is this whole relationship between `liveSounds` and how you're selecting by name. Without more context I can't say for sure, but it seems like maybe you can have `liveSounds = {}` with the name being the key and that would make everything much simpler.

You *do* need to think if sounds need to get disposed of or what happens if you invoke a method for something without a name, or if there's two things with the same name.

Also, as always, I'm going to go ahead and say the prodigious use of `this` here is probably entirely unnecessary and you can just use a factory method instead of a constructor.

Also, it's 2015, can't we just start using es6 already?

Comment: liveSounds will note work with a name key because every time a new sound is played a new live sound is added, and if it has the same name, that previous sound will be lost.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew ok, so that was something that I wasn't clear on what you desired - in this case an object where the values are arrays `{name: [sounds]}` might still be a better fit. As for splice - fair enough, but I guarantee you in 90% of the code you see, copying is done with `slice`. Might as well do the conventional thing and save yourself a letter :)

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew - note I rolled back your code-edit. Please post a follow-on question instead (see the comment I added to your question for a link).

Comment: @rolfl I think that edit was with the more info as we requested, I don't think there was enough time to incorporate my feedback

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Observing your code more I have to say that there is a lot that *I* don't see fit in my code. Especially the `this.sound` function. The prototype needed to be called because I was overwriting the `play()` function of the audio instance. I use `this` because it stills refers to the instance it's attached too.  "this.onended = function(){ liveSounds.splice( liveSounds.indexOf(snd), 1 );};" was absolutely mandatory for my code to work and clean itself out of the live code. Sounds aren't reset, if anything they're being killed, and your `liveSoundsExcept` function reversed my code...

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I do like your functional approach though. And I know that my code was hard to understand with the lack of extra information. I would use the functional approach you implemented, but my only draw back is that I am trying to save every bit of processing power I can, and I believe my non filter approach will be just a tad faster. For it quickly escapes, and it doesn't need to iterate over the array more than once.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Also I'm sorry for saying splice copys an array, I actually did mean Slice(); like you said :)

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew I suggest implementing with a focus on architecture first. Then you can profile and work on your performance bottlenecks.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew a) don't assume a style of programming will affect performance. These seem like user controls which will be called maybe what...a couple times per second max? That's many orders of magnitude slower than performance could possibly matter. As for the whole thing with `this`, I assure you, its not necessary - `this` in javascript is not like `this` in OO languages (even though it looks like it). I have an explanation on my blog http://togakangaroo.github.io/2014/11/10/dont-teach-oojs and in my thee npm module https://github.com/togakangaroo/thee#we-dont-all-agree-that-this-is-dumb

Comment: @Schism I've already changed a **lot** of this code. Would I be able to upload something like a "verison 2"?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I am very familiar with the `this` member. It is a property of functions and can be tossed around when you don't understand where you put it. On the other hand, mine is perfectly valid and offers a lot more adjustability. If a user wanted to use "apply" on my "play" it would work. Either you don't understand what my code is doing, or you don't understand how inheritance works, but I made a demonstration to show you why yours wouldn't work and that my use of this is perfectly valid: http://jsfiddle.net/u2uqqdb7/1/ . `this` is not as confusing as others make it to be.

Comment: I've posted a new question with better design and further information about the design of my system: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96138/improved-sound-control-system